# Is it possible to let `i3-msg` wait until some window is shown?

Tags: i3-window-manager

Is it possible to use `i3-msg` somehow to wait for a window of some class to be shown on the desktop before continuing?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question; I was misunderstanding the documentation of `i3-msg`. It is possible to wait for some window event as follows:

`$ i3-msg -t subscribe '[ "window" ]'`

In my case, I wanted to wait for some event of a specific window class, 'build_output' in this case, which can be done as follows:

`$ i3-msg -m -t subscribe '[ "window" ]' | grep -q build_output`

The `-m` option is needed to keep on monitoring window events after one is received, then the `-q` option for grep will stop the command once some window event contains the window class name. A bit rough maybe, but it works for my use case.

Maybe monitoring for window events for some specific window class can be done without having to resort to `grep`, but I have not yet found how to do that.